Blazor Web App nuget package missing static files from external nugets
I have a Blazor Web App recently upgraded from Blazor Server. As part of the process it is packed to a nuget. After the upgrade I noticed that when you pack the project it is missing static files like css and js from referenced nugets.
For example this line in App.razor does not seem to do the work anymore.
<link href="_content/Radzen.Blazor/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />

I had to copy paste entire CSS from dev tools and reference it as "my own" file.
This is how my project file looks like
    <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="bin/Release/net8.0/**/*.*">
        <PackagePath>Test</PackagePath>
        <Pack>true</Pack>
    </Content>
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <None Include="wwwroot/**/*.*">
        <Pack>true</Pack>
        <PackagePath>Test/wwwroot/</PackagePath>
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
</ItemGroup>        

Can anyone help?

its changed for .net 8 i believe
use like this, but still reference the js file.
<RadzenTheme Theme="material" @rendermode="InteractiveAuto" />

https://blazor.radzen.com/get-started?theme=material3

Did that, but it does not seem to work. Cannot find a way to reference or force external css to be included in my package

i see what you mean, so its just not loading the radzen css?

it is loading when app is run locally, no problem with that. But I need to pack all this to a nuget and run through CI/CD. It is complicated. It is used to transfer betweeen devops organizations. In the end Docker image is built.
But when I try to pack it locally I do not see RAdzen css in wwwroot folder. And then it is missing after deploy.

or maybe I do not need to pack it as a physical file, but find a way to reference it from that dll. It all worked fine in Blazor server .NET7.

ok, that is strange if it worked on .net 7, im assuming theres no documentation on it for "migrating to .net8" although i cant see to find any migrating guides
